# Datagridview cell not committing after edit (Bound to database)

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell, commit, edit

So, I have a datagridview bound to a database. And I am using this code to commit changes after cell edit. But it's not committing the changes to the database. After I fill my dataSet the cell's value resets. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
  private void dgvDatabase_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

          dgvDatabase.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
          gASFLESSENBindingSource1.EndEdit();  
  }
```

Comment: You will need to call the `Update` method on the dataset for the changes to move back to the database.

Comment: Ah, knew I forgot something little. Thanks, it has solved my problem.